# Crystal Report Exported to PDF from .NET Application Doesn't Always Refresh

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I have an application the creates a series of reports for users and exports them to PDF. The reports are created using Crystal Reports bound to a Microsoft Access database (legacy reasons, not my choice). I have found that the PDF data is not always exported. In some cases, say I create 3 user reports in a row, the PDF will contain the data from the first user in all 3 of the users' PDF files. The behaviour is not consistent tho, sometimes the 2nd user will be exported correctly, but the third export will contain the data for the second user. I am lost as to why this is happening, but my best guess is that the Crystal Report is not fully refreshed before it's exported to PDF. Does this make sense? Should I use the RefreshReport event and do the export there?

The only other option is that the database has not been updated at the time of the export, but I have put some testing code to check the DB right before the export and the data is correct. Any suggestions? Here is the code that does the Exporting:

```
crystalReport.Refresh();

foreach (Parameter parameter in reportParameters)
        crystalReport.SetParameterValue(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);

ExportOptions crystalReportExportOptions;
DiskFileDestinationOptions crystalReportDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
PdfRtfWordFormatOptions crystalReportFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
crystalReportDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = pdfExportPath;
crystalReportExportOptions = crystalReport.ExportOptions;
{
    crystalReportExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
    crystalReportExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
    crystalReportExportOptions.DestinationOptions = crystalReportDiskFileDestinationOptions;
    crystalReportExportOptions.FormatOptions = crystalReportFormatTypeOptions;
}

crystalReport.Export();
```

The most curious part of this is that if I add the following line after crystalReport.Refresh(), it works:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
```

Of course this is an unacceptable hack, but what is the correct solution?